# Apache virtualhosts: different paths serve different application on same IP

Tags: apache, apache2, virtualhost

I have setup on my local network an Ubuntu server with Apache2 on it.

I would like to manage different applications on the same server, when you request an url a dedicated application is served.

E.g.

```
http://192.168.0.25/my_app_1 -> responds with app1 (for example a Ruby on Rails app)
http://192.168.0.25/my_app_2 -> responds with app2 (for example a php website)
[...]
# where 192.168.0.25 is the IP of the server
```

I think that this is done by configuring correctly the virtualhosts in Apache2.

At this moment, a sample configuration of app1 (i.e. Ruby on Rails) is like the followed:

```
<VirtualHost 192.168.0.25:80>
 DocumentRoot path_to_my_public_app1_folder
 <Directory path_to_my_public_app1_folder>
  Options -MultiViews
  AllowOverride All
 </Directory>
 RailsEnv production
</VirtualHost>
```

How can define the sub path? Maybe something like this?

```
<VirtualHost 192.168.0.25/my_app1:80>
```

Am I doing it right?
Because at this moment I recieve a 404 (not even the custom Apache page "It's work!")

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`VirtualHost` means something different. It allows you (in short) to host sites responding to different names, e.g.:

```
http://mydomain.com
http://anotherdomain.com
```

on the same server. So think of it as virtual appaches, all on the same machine, but identified by different names.

Your usecase is different. You want to configure the instance `192.168.0.25` and how it serves different requests. So the part after the host in the URL: `http://HOST/PATH_TO_APP`

For the instance responding to `192.168.0.25` you should edit the default config in

```
/etc/apache2/sites-available/default
```

You can add the following:

```
Alias /my_app_1 path_to_my_public_app1_folder
Alias /my_app_2 path_to_my_public_app2_folder
```